# Is there an error in these HTTP request headers?

Tags: http, connection, transfer-encoding

I'm trying to write a .NET web API that will receive HTTP requests from some devices and handle the data sent. I know the exact format of the data being sent and the ip/port that the data is sent to. The problem is that the API does not even seem to respond to the request as the controller method to handle the POST is never called.

I have tested the API with Postman; using the correct data format and host information and it works as intended. In order to ensure some kind of connection attempt is being made by the device, I listened to the port using a nodejs TCP server. There is data being sent and this is the header info that precedes it:

```
POST / HTTP/1.0
Host: xxx
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: xxx
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Transfer-Content: chunked
```

I can't post the body data, but it is in JSON format as expected (but separated into chunks).
Since there are requests being made, data being sent but the API doesn't acknowledge it despite working when tested using Postman, I'm wondering if there is an issue with the head. I've been researching about the headers and I did read that HTTP 1.0 doesn't support chunked transfer-encoding. Could it be that the devices are making erroneous requests? Or are the headers fine and the problem could be elsewhere?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is a HTTP/1.1 feature, so the device is certainly making an erroneous request.  If the .NET implementation is strict about this, it won't accept the header and won't understand the encoded body. But you should get some error notification somewhere - a HTTP error code returned to the client making this wrong request, and some logging on the server.

Comment: The client device is unfortunately a black box, but I will try to see if I can use server logging to pinpoint the issue. Thanks.

Comment: The black box presumably has some vendor, and if it turns out that the error is in their firmware you might be entitled to a bugfix firmware upgrade.